# Pandas - Minimum rate and corresponding supplier name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, minimum

[I am currently analyzing some price data and would like to know if it is possible to get the lowest rate per lane id and the corresponding name of the supplier who offered the cheapest rate in pandas dataframe]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfxnR.png)

[Below is my expected output. df[['quoted_rates']].idxmin() but it is not giving all the information that I would like to have. Please help me. Appreciate the support, thank you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAdBf.png)

Comment: please don't use image, provide your data in a reproducible format (**text**)

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['Supplier 1', 'Lane 1', 'NL', 'DE', 200],
        ['Supplier 2', 'Lane 1', 'NL', 'DE', 150],
        ['Supplier 3', 'Lane 1', 'NL', 'DE', 300],
        ['Supplier 1', 'Lane 2', 'NL', 'DE', 200],
        ['Supplier 2', 'Lane 2', 'NL', 'DE', 105],
        ['Supplier 3', 'Lane 2', 'NL', 'DE', 100]]

columns = ['supplier_name', 'lane_id', 'origin', 'destination', 'quoted_rates']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
```

```
df.sort_values(by='quoted_rates').groupby('lane_id',as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
    lane_id     supplier_name   origin  destination     quoted_rates
0   Lane 1      Supplier 2      NL      DE              150
1   Lane 2      Supplier 3      NL      DE              100
```

In Addition:

```
new = df.sort_values(by='quoted_rates').groupby('lane_id',as_index=False).first()

field = 'supplier_name'
df['min_supplier'] = df.apply(lambda x:new[new.lane_id==x.lane_id][field].iloc[0],axis=1)
```

```
    supplier_name   lane_id  origin  destination    quoted_rates    min_supplier
0   Supplier 1      Lane 1   NL      DE             200             Supplier 2
1   Supplier 2      Lane 1   NL      DE             150             Supplier 2
2   Supplier 3      Lane 1   NL      DE             300             Supplier 2
3   Supplier 1      Lane 2   NL      DE             200             Supplier 3
4   Supplier 2      Lane 2   NL      DE             105             Supplier 3
5   Supplier 3      Lane 2   NL      DE             100             Supplier 3
```

Comment: Small update: What if I would like to create another column in the main dataframe and update this column with the name of supplier who had the cheapest rate? Thanks a lot for your help